# Call of Session.get() hangs after several calls

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I wanted to save many entities using Hibernates Session in one call, so i created this code:

```
public void persistOrUpdateAllTrades(List<Trade> objects) {
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();

try {
    FlushMode lastFlushMode = session.getFlushMode();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

    for(Trade trade: objects) {
        if(session.get(Trade.class, trade.getId()) == null){
            session.save((Object)trade);
        }
    }

    session.flush();
    session.setFlushMode(lastFlushMode);

} catch (Throwable e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

}

It usually works well, but sometimes execution stops/hangs at `if(session.get(Trade.class, trade.getId()) == null)` and i have no idea why. It doesn't throw any exception, and application doesn't stop. Application uses MySQL server running at localhost. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the EntityManager. This is leaks resources, most often connections from a connection pool. Eventually the pool has no more connections available, so it just blocks until it gets a connection available (which in your case is never). The quick fix would just be to do a `entityManager.close()` at the bottom of your method.